# How large can a set of nearly equidistant points be?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose that $D$ is a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ such that all pairwise distances between them belong to $[1,1+\epsilon]$.

It seems that such a set cannot be very large and that its cardinality should be bounded from above by some function of $k$ and $\epsilon$.

Is such a bound known?

Comment: $D$ can be exponential in $k$. This follows, for example, from the Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma, which you can find via Google.

Comment: @BillJohnson JL says that *if* I have such a set in a higher dimension $n \approx e^{k}$ , then I can embed it into $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ while (almost) preserving the distance property. But I don't see how it guarantees the existence of such a set to begin with. Am I missing something here? P.S. JL does not assume anything on the relation of the pairwise distances to each other, while in this case I need to. P.P.S. The question actually originates in an attempt to understand a result related to JL. :)

Comment: A similar argument as the solution of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30270/maximum-number-of-mutually-equidistant-points-in-an-n-dimensional-euclidean-spac?rq=1 yields that for $\epsilon$ small enough the set $D$ contains at most $k+1$ elements

Comment: Apply JL to an orthonormal set in a high dimensional space; all the pairwise distance are the same, so you get almost the same in the low dimensional space.

Comment: As shown by the above comments, when $\varepsilon$ is fixed and $k\to\infty$, $|D|$ can typically be exponential, but when $k$ is fixed and $\varepsilon\to 0$, then $|D|\le k+1$. So the interplay between the two parameters is subtle, and you should probably give more details on which regime interests you to get useful answers.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner I am more interested in $\epsilon>\frac{1}{n-1}$ and fixed.

Comment: JL says any $m$ points in a Hilbert space $1+\epsilon$-embeds into a Hilbert space of dimension at most $c\epsilon^{-2} \log m$ for some constant $c$ independent of $m$ and $\epsilon$. That is sharp up to $\log (1/\epsilon)$.