# Equidistant points on a compact Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. To this Riemannian manifold, we associate a natural number $K(M,g)$ as follows:

$K(M,g)$ is the maximum of all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that we have at least $n$ distinct points $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in M$ such that $d(x_i,x_j)$ is independent of $i\neq j$.

What is this number for the round sphere $S^n$?

Does $K(M,g)$ depends on the Riemannian metric $g$?

Comment: You can fit at most n+1 equidistant points in R^n, and so there are at most n+1 euclidean-equidistant points in the round sphere in R^n. Since geodesic distance is determined by euclidean distance, this solves the problem for the round sphere. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30270/maximum-number-of-mutually-equidistant-points-in-an-n-dimensional-euclidean-spac

Answer (score 3):

$K(M,g)$ depends on the metric, as shown by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417896/can-we-make-distances-in-a-finite-subset-of-a-manifold-whatever-we-want), which implies that we can change the metric of $\mathbb{R}^3$ so it has as many points pairwise at distance $1$ as we want.

Comment: thank you  very much for your answer  and  your attention to my question